# c++ issue while(cin>>str) and ctrl+z

Tags: c++

Read a sequence of strings from cin and cout these strings which like:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string str;
 while(cin>>str)
 {
     cout<<str<<endl;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Now ,I have some inputs

aa bb cc ^Z dd ee

print Enter , the output is:

aa

bb

cc

Then I input

ff gg

Print Enter,the output is:

->ff

gg

like below :
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfFa7.png)

The question is :why the ^Z in the first line is not be used as EOF ,but be output as a '->' before "ff" at the second output ?And why the strings(such as "dd ee") are ignored after the ^Z in the first input.

Comment: If I press <Ctrl>-Z (which I assume is what your `^Z` is meant to mean), the program is suspended and I am looking at a bash shell prompt. ;-) What is your environment? Windows command shell?

Comment: You should name your operating system. `Strg+Z` and other keycombinations depend on the operating system. Are you using *Microsoft Windows 7*? Your image loocks like that.

Comment: Yes ,my operating system is Microsoft Windows 7, and the IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I don't know enough about the mechanics behind the scene to explain what happes. I even dont know, what the `→` means. But as far as I know, you have to press `Enter` after pressing `Strg+Z`. `aa bb cc ^Z⏎` should work.

Comment: On many platforms, the Enter key signals the end of buffering input; then the input is passed to the requestors.  The OS may interpret a ^Z at the end of an input buffer as terminating the input.  In the middle of input it may be a character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes，thanks your answer,but I want to know if ^Z is a character in the middle of input ,why the strings "dd ee" are ignored ,and when I first press enter ,the '->' isn't be output ?